# JavaScript Fade in too fast after 2 pictures

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

Im having a little problem in javascript that after 2 images it dosent fade in as slow as the other pictures see here: [click me!](http://theblueraven.no-ip.org/test2) I dont have a clue to do anymore i have tried my best to fix it but no succes. NOTE: Im a noob on this so try to explain as simple as possible :)

Javascript code:

```
sliderInt = 1;
sliderNext = 2;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#slider > img#1").fadeIn(4000);
    startSlider();
    $("#slider > img#" + sliderNext).fadeIn(4000);
});

function startSlider() {
    count = $("#slider > img").size();

    loop = setInterval(function() {

        if(sliderNext > count) {
            sliderNext = 1;
            sliderInt = 1;
        }

        $("#slider > img").fadeOut(4000);
        $("#slider > img#" + sliderNext).fadeIn(4000);

        sliderInt = sliderNext;
        sliderNext = sliderNext + 1;

    }, 10000);

}
```

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MonsterCat | Made By TheRavenBlue</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slider.css">
</head>
<body>
<body style="background-color:black;">

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/slider.js"></script>

    <div class="wrapper">

        <div id="slider">
            <img id="1" src="images/image1.png">
            <img id="2" src="images/image2.png">
            <img id="3" src="images/image3.png">
            <img id="4" src="images/image4.png">
        </div>

        <a href="#">Previous</a>
        <a href="#">Next</a>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey on my Mac with the last Chrome the images always fade at the same rate !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here seems to be that the in `startSlider()` , the `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` are happening simultaneously (You can observe this by using chrome inspect element. Inline css style of both current and next image should show opacities being changed simultaneously), so you should call the `fadeOut()` as a callback on completion of `fadeIn`

sliderInt = 1;
sliderNext = 2;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#slider > img#1").fadeIn(4000);
    startSlider();
    $("#slider > img#" + sliderNext).fadeIn(4000);
});

```
function startSlider() {
    count = $("#slider > img").size();

    loop = setInterval(function () {

        if (sliderNext > count) {
            sliderNext = 1;
            sliderInt = 1;
        }

        $("#slider > img").fadeOut(4000, function () {
            $("#slider > img#" + sliderNext).fadeIn(4000);
        });

        sliderInt = sliderNext;
        sliderNext = sliderNext + 1;

    }, 10000);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fadeIn and fadeOut happen asynchronously.  (It appears that you want your images to fade in and out at the same time, like a smooth transition.)  So, when you have a fade durration of 4000 and a loop duration of 10000, your non-transitioning time will be 6000.  to wait till after the fade on a fade call, add the callback as the second param.

```
$foo.fadeIn(4000, fSomeCallback);
```

Instead, use closures to reference your list, and then you don't need to reference the image Id's at all.

Try this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $slider = $('#slider');
    var $slides = $slider.find('img').hide();
    var iImgIndex = 0;
    var iFadeDuration = 4000;
    var iLoopDuration = 10000;
    var fSwapSlide = function ($in, $out) {
        $in.fadeIn(iFadeDuration);
        if ($out != null) {
            $out.fadeOut(iFadeDuration);
        }
    };
    var fPlayLoop = function () {
        var $out = $slides.eq(iImgIndex);
        iImgIndex++;
        iImgIndex = iImgIndex == $slides.size() ? 0 : iImgIndex;
        var $in = $slides.eq(iImgIndex);
        fSwapSlide($in, $out);
    };
    // init
    fSwapSlide($slides.eq(0), null);
    // to start it 
    var tLoopTimer = setInterval(fPlayLoop, iLoopDuration);
    // to wait till all the images are done loading before you begin:
    //$(window).ready(fPlayLoop);
});
```